# How to control range of rows while loading csv file into sqltable using ssis

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a csv file.The format of csv file is something like this:

```
[A    src   dt]
[col1 col2 col3 col4 col5]
[1     2    3     4    5]
[1     2    3     4    5]
[n     n    n     n    n]
[z    src   dt]
```

I want to load data up to n row.I don't want the last row.
I can skip the first row in flate file connection manager editor.But how can i skip the last row while inserting data into sqltable.

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the rows into a staging table in your DB, then use some T-SQL to move all but the last row into the recipient table.

You could probably do something with a script transformation in your dataflow to do what you ask solely using SSIS, but it would be a lot more work than the above staging table method.

Answer (score 0):

That is the job for the Script Task:) Write a simple c#/VB script that checks whether it's the last row in the flow (hasMoreRows i think is the property) and redirect row to appropriate output (or simply eat it:)

Luke